Golang delve in Kubernetes container - "use of closed network connection"
Edit: Before you go through the entire question, note the update at the end (the pod restarts were caused by a liveness probe failing). I am not deleting the question, because:

it links to a very nice article from @DazWilkin with a tutorial for this scenario
it can still be useful for other people encountering similar issues
I still have not figured out why the application was not starting (but since I can no longer reproduce that, I can only assume there was some kind of PEBKAC/10-T error )

I am attempting to use Delve to debug an application running remotely, on Kubernetes. The application is an HTTP server (using Gin), so it should start before the remote debugger connects.
Locally, using Docker, everything seems to work fine - the container logs on startup look like this:
API server listening at: [::]:2345
2024-05-27T06:56:35Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2024-05-27T06:56:35Z info layer=debugger launching process with args: [/usr/src/app/bin/app]
2024-05-27T06:56:35Z debug layer=debugger Adding target 11 "/usr/src/app/bin/app"
2024-05-27T06:56:35Z debug layer=debugger continuing
2024-05-27T06:56:35Z debug layer=debugger ContinueOnce
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
...
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :8080

So the debugger starts correctly, and starts the application as well.
However, the same container image started on Kubernetes results in this container log:
API server listening at: [::]:2345
2024-05-27T06:49:17Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2024-05-27T06:49:17Z info layer=debugger launching process with args: [/usr/src/app/bin/app]
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z debug layer=debugger Adding target 12 "/usr/src/app/bin/app"
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z debug layer=debugger continuing
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z debug layer=debugger ContinueOnce
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z debug layer=debugger callInjection protocol on:
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z debug layer=debugger       17 PC=0x4783b7
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z debug layer=debugger       18 PC=0x478983
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z debug layer=debugger       20 PC=0x478983
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z debug layer=debugger       12 PC=0x440944
2024-05-27T06:49:18Z error layer=rpc writing response:write tcp [::1]:2345->[::1]:33826: use of closed network connection

The actual (Gin) application never starts, and the pod exits and is automatically restarted.
Can anyone point me in the right direction for solving this?
K8s version 1.29.3 (vanilla k8s), containerd://1.7.13, calico networking, on Ubuntu 22.04.3. Container based on golang:1.22-alpine, dockerfile below:
FROM golang:1.22-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

COPY . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/src

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
  go mod download && go mod verify

RUN \
  --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
  --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \
  go build -v -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o ../bin/app 

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 2345

CMD ["dlv", "--listen=:2345", "--api-version=2", "--headless=true", "--accept-multiclient", "--continue", "--log", "exec", "/usr/src/app/bin/app"]

Adding some details, as per the request in the comments:

K8s is "vanilla" k8s (no specific distribution), installed via Kubespray.
There is no NodePort (and no service) configured for port 2345 yet, precisely because I was trying to troubleshoot this error that looks like something from the outside connecting to :2345
There is no IDE config yet - the error occurred as soon as I attempted to run the pod on K8s, before I could even attempt to connect to it from the IDE (VSCode)

Update: the pod restart was due to the liveness probe failing, since the Gin process (which should have replied to the probe) never started correctly. And, most likely, the "closed network connection" occurred when the delve process was terminated.
The one thing I was not able to figure out is why the debugged process was not starting (notice that it started correctly in a local Docker container). But I can no longer reproduce that now :(

It looks (!?) as though the API server is listening on the Kubernetes service's (host's?) NodePort (33826) rather than 2345 directly. Please update your question with details of your Kubernetes Deployment and your IDE config. Your question prompted me to try remote debugging and I'm able to get it to work (albeit not using Gin) and use kubectl port-forward to the Deployment to use the same ports (which may be worth your testing too)

Updated the question. There is no NodePort configured for the 2345 container port (precisely because I wanted to exclude the chance of anything external actually connecting to the port). The port listed in the logs actually changes from one run to another (and as far as I am able to read the logs, that looks like the port at the other end of the connection to :2345).
I mentioned Gin because I have seen similar errors in other questions from people using Gin - but since I never found a solution, I do not know if the use of Gin is relevant or not.

How are you deploying the container to Kubernetes (Deployment?)? How are you accessing the deployed container without a Service? Are you using kubectl port-forward? When I run my repro of your issue, I get the log equivalent to Adding target 12 but then it blocks awaiting the connection. I only receive debugger continuing and debugger ContinueOnce once I connect the remote debugger. You say you're not starting remote debugging before this occurs. Is it possible that something else is connecting to whatever port you're publishing?

The continuing and ContinueOnce are (I believe) due to the --continue argument to dlv. There is a service for port 8080 (the Gin router port), but no service yet for 2345 (the delve port). However, I seem to have missed something during my original testing, because now I can no longer reproduce the same behavior. So please let us put this on hold while I investigate further, trying to find out what has changed. Thank you!!

You got it! Your question piqued my curiosity and led me to learn for myself how to do this.

That is a very nice (and fast! :) ) writeup. Thank you!

As for the original question, the reason why the pod was restarting was a liveness probe that was failing. And, probably, the "closed network connection" happened when the processes were killed. What I cannot figure out, though, is why the debugged process was not starting correctly (causing the liveness probe to fail). But since I am no longer able to reproduce the issue, I will have to leave it here. I will update the question with all details - I wouldn't delete it, because it is still a learning opportunity. Thank you once again for all your help!

You're welcome! I suspect because Delve blocks the process until a debugger attaches

That is the problem, it shouldn't have blocked it (that is why I had --continue in the command-line arguments, to ensure that the debugged process starts correctly before the remote debugger is attached. Note that it started correctly in the local container. But since I cannot reproduce, I guess the reason for this will remain a mistery... :) Once again, thank you!
